# Склоняется ли слово "коала"?

Tags: грамматика

On some sites коала, коалы, коале, коалу, коалой/коалою, коале

On some sites коала, коала, коала, коала, коала, коала

What is right?

Comment: In modern word it is склоняемое

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it often happens, this word had been borrowed as indeclinable into Russian, but had later accepted declension as more people were becoming familiar with it.

In older texts it's indeclinable:

> - Живут коала на ветвях особого вида эвкалиптов и питаются листьями. [коллективный. Из почты «Огонька» // «Огонек». № 34, 1956]
> - Вероятно, возрастающее внимание общественности к этому яркому шустрому зверьку сможет сохранить ему жизнь, как оно когда-то помогло спасти коала в Восточной Австралии. [Клуб Почемучек // «Юный натуралист», 1976]

, in newer ones it does decline:

> - Зоопарк, наверное, выполнил свой годовой план, постоять в очереди к коале пришел и мэр города. [Ирина Соколова. Бабочки летают (заметки о Тайване) (1999)]
> - Австралийскому сумчатому медведю коале бесполезно предлагать морковку или бутерброд с сыром. [Т. Подоскина. Нескучная латынь // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

Dictionaries don't agree on declinability and gender either: Lopatin treats it as declinable feminine or indeclinable masculine; Zarva's *Русское словесное ударение* says it's masculine and indeclinable; *Большой Толковый Словарь* (the 1998's edition) says it's declinable feminine.

Answer (score 3):

This is a two-stage process. First, we get used to the name and correlate it with similarly sounding (gorilla, zebra, [panthera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panthera) and so on). Next, we transfer all declination forms onto it, because this seems natural. So, koala becomes feminine, although it has also male connotations (медведь, а не медведица). Russians tend to thinks that words ending with "a" are feminine.

(my private opinion is that koala is not declinable - because it does not drink)